# Take specifics date in log file and process it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to process a log file that contains events log, but only **today** logs.

The log file looks like this:

```sh
Aug 23 07:23:05 iZk1a211s8hkb4hkecu7w1Z sshd[19569]: Invalid user test from 10.148.0.13 port 48382
...
Sep 20 07:23:06 iZk1a211s8hkb4hkecu7w1Z sshd[19569]: Failed password for invalid user test from 10.148.0.13 port 48382 ssh2
...
Aug 23 07:23:07 iZk1a211s8hkb4hkecu7w1Z sshd[19564]: Failed password for invalid user sysadm from 10.148.0.13 port 48380 ssh2
...
Oct 15 07:23:09 iZk1a211s8hkb4hkecu7w1Z sshd[19573]: Invalid user sinusbot from 10.148.0.13 port 48384
...
Sep 08 07:23:11 iZk1a211s8hkb4hkecu7w1Z sshd[19573]: Failed password for invalid user sinusbot from 10.148.0.13 port 48384 ssh2
...
Nov 01 07:23:16 iZk1a211s8hkb4hkecu7w1Z sshd[19587]: Invalid user smkim from 10.148.0.13 port 48386
...
Nov 12 07:23:18 iZk1a211s8hkb4hkecu7w1Z sshd[19587]: Failed password for invalid user smkim from 10.148.0.13 port 48386 ssh2
```

How to grab the today line in the log?

I've tried this and got stuck in finding the patterns:

```py
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
today = today.strftime("%B %d")

with  open('file.log','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        date = line.find("*idk I'm stuck at this point*")
        if date = today:
           `*run my process script*`
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You can use regular expressions to extract patterns from strings. Or, if you know that the first X characters of each line are a date, use `datetime.datetime.strptime`

Comment: You dont have the year in the log - is that right?

Comment: @ForceBru Thank you I will try your suggestion out.

Comment: @balderman yes it's true

Comment: So how can you tell if a specific line is today?

Comment: @balderman damn you're correct.. It would be damned if the log contains events more than a year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the part of the string containing the date, parse it as `datetime` and convert it to a `date`:

```py
from datetime import date
today: date = date.today()

with open('file.log','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        date: date = datetime.strptime(line[:15], "%b %d %H:%M:%S").date().replace(year=today.year)
        if date == today:
           `*run my process script*`
```

Comment: Sorry, meant `%b`. Fixed

Comment: when I tried to convert the string to date using your script `date = datetime.strptime(line[:15], "%b %d %H:%M:%S").date()` but it gives the wrong year. We don't want any year, please look at this https://imgur.com/a/t2fVqoN

Comment: I modify it to:
`from datetime import date
today = today.today()
today = today.strftime("%b %d")

with open('file.log','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        date = datetime.strptime(line[:15], "%b %d %H:%M:%S").date()
       date = date.strftime("%b %d")
        if date == today:
           `*run my process script*`

Comment: It works, please edit your answer and I will accept it as the answer

Comment: Why do you convert `today` and `date` into `str`'s? Doesn't comparing the dates directly work?

Comment: No it's not work. Because in my log I have no years then it assigns automatically year 1980, when today's date is 2020 so it won't work and I need to convert to str 's